# Android OpenGL reflection/environment texture

Tags: android, opengl-es

Where can I find some good examples of using reflection maps? Is it possible in `OpenGL ES 1.0`? I tried to use `glTexEnvx`, but i don't know how to use it. I also have some questions:

1) Does reflection map requires a texture coordinates? In programs like 3ds max - it doesn't.
   2) Can i change reflectivity vs. angle dependency (to make some kind of fresnel effect) without writing shaders?
  3) Can i use black/white texture to mask reflection on diffuse material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glTexEnv` sets things like how samples from a texture combine with the material colour. It won't do environment mapping. On fixed pipeline desktop OpenGL you'd probably use `glTexGen`. There's no `glTexGen` in OpenGL ES.

What you can do instead is take advantage of the texture matrix stack. ES doesn't support 3d textures but it does support 3d texture coordinates. So duplicate your vertex normals into texture coordinates and ensure that you load the texture matrix stack with the normal matrix (which is just the rotational part of the transform from object space to world space if you have no scaling). That way you'll end up with 3d texture coordinates that are equivalent to the world-space normals. Leaving GL to use those as a 2d index into a texture will allow you to use a sphere map for environment mapping.

It's not an Android example, but the best online example I can find that doesn't do anything silly like doing the normal calculations (explicitly) on the CPU is [this one](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-441D327D-D737-42A2-BCEA-FE89FBCA2F35/OpenGLEx/EnvMapping/doc/index.html) from Nokia's old Symbian/Series 60 examples. The linked article explains the approach and includes a link to a .cpp that implements it. OpenGL ES is the same between platforms, extensions aside, so it should port directly to Android.

1. not in the sense that you're asking; the concept is that a textured non-rotating primitive surrounds the object — environment map coordinates for each vertex are calculated by casting a ray from the vertex along its normal out until it hits the conceptual bounding geometry and working out the texture coordinate there. So you need valid normals but you needn't supply texture coordinates.
2. not really, at least as I understand it; Fresnel effects depend on the angle between you and a surface whereas environment mapping depends only on object rotation in world space.
3. yes, but you'll quite possibly end up having to use multiple rendering passes. ES requires at least two texturing units to be available so you can do at least environment + mask — if you have other components to apply you can do multiple renderings while getting everything to accumulate in the frame buffer.